Как записать отдельно значения из массива в json файл и добавить необходимый текст
Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста не знаю python но не нужно сделать вывод информации в js файл:
есть массив данных с помощью него пытаюсь сделать автоматическое создание js фала
obj = []

for item in file_image :
    obj.append({
                'file':'images/'+ item,
                'timeout': 10000,
                'type': f'image'})

with open('playlist.js', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(obj, f, indent=4)


Результат:
[
    {
        "file": "images/png-clipart-person-computer-icons-stick-figure-free-content-free-animated-s-website-stockxchng.png",
        "timeout": 10000,
        "type": "image"
    },
    {
        "file": "images/png-transparent-ghost-drawing-halloween-ghost-pics-white-marine-mammal-fictional-character.png",
        "timeout": 10000,
        "type": "image"
    },
    {
        "file": "images/01.jpg",
        "timeout": 10000,
        "type": "image"
    },
    {
        "file": "images/02.jpg",
        "timeout": 10000,
        "type": "image"
    }
]

Необходимо дописать перед квадратной ковычкой: "view":
Как правильно это будет сделать?

Значит нужно обернуть ваш список который в obj ещё в словарь с ключом view:
json.dump({'view': obj}, f, indent=4)

Кстати, вы используете f-строки там, где это не нужно и не используете там, где можно было бы. То есть лучше так:
    obj.append({
                'file':f'images/{item}',
                'timeout': 10000,
                'type': 'image'})


Огромное спасибо!

Если ответ вам подошёл (проверьте ещё, вдруг что-то не так), то отметьте его специальной галочкой.
